# How to get a Unique ID for a list of strings?

Tags: java

How can I get a Unique ID (as a integer) for a List of Strings?

E.g. the list looks like `["Cat","Dog","Cow","Cat","Rat"]`
the result should be:

```
1 -> Cat
2 -> Dog
3 -> Cow
4 -> Rat
```

I need to save this and new structure.

EDIT: Its important, that `Cat` is only one time in the new structure.

Comment: Could you possibly use an enum for this?

Comment: Not sure what you're after here. What would be the data type of the output you want? Or better yet, assuming you had what you want, show us an example of how you would use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `HashMap<Integer, String>`. The key would be the index in your current `List`, while the value would be the actual `String`.

Example:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
// no identical Strings here
Set<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
myList.add("Cat"); // index 0
myList.add("Dog"); // index 1
myList.add("Cow"); // etc
myList.add("Cat");
myList.add("Rat");
mySet.add("Cat"); // index 0
mySet.add("Dog"); // index 1
mySet.add("Cow"); // etc
mySet.add("Cat"); // index 0 - already there
mySet.add("Rat");
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    myMap.put(i, myList.get(i));
}
System.out.println(myMap);
Map<Integer, String> myOtherMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
int i = 0;
for (String animal: mySet) {
    myOtherMap.put(i++, animal);
}
System.out.println(myOtherMap);
```

Output:

```
{0=Cat, 1=Dog, 2=Cow, 3=Cat, 4=Rat}
{0=Cat, 1=Dog, 2=Cow, 3=Rat}
```

Comment: But when I use the index of my List I will have the Cat two times in it but it should be there just one time.

Comment: @gurehbgui so you want to remove the identical Strings from your List before mapping them? Or do you just need to remove identicals, no mapping? **Edit** in the latter case, you could just use HashSet<String> instead of ArrayList<String> as Uncle Iroh mentions.

Comment: Use a HashSet instead of a List.

Comment: You are adding the Cat twice, check whether it already exists in the map. If not then only add.

Comment: Ok just edited my answer with a LinkedHashSet solution and mapping if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only unique within a process, then you can use an `AtomicInteger` and call `incrementAndGet()` each time you need a new value.

Else you can try this

```
int uniqueId = 0;

int getUniqueId()
{
    return uniqueId++;
}
```

Add synchronized if you want it to be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
private enum Animals {
   Cat,
   Dog,
   Cow,
   Sheep,
   Horse 
}
```

`Animals.Cat.ordinal()` -- gives you the number.
`Animals.valueOf("Cat");` -- match strings with.

Comment: This is not possible becuase the list is must more longer.

Answer (score 1):

1. build a set containing the values.
2. build an array containing the set values (see Set.toArray()).
3. The index of the item in array is the integer identifier for the item.